# Cypress: child command subject seems not to be an element

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

I have a `fillInput()` function that takes a selector and a value as parameters, then:

- clear the the input via `cy.get(selector).clear()`
- then fills the input value via `cy.get(selector).type(value)`

As far as I know, this is really some sort of anti-pattern and [a cypress command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax) should be the way to go.

So, [reading about child commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Child-Commands), I came out with this command that should do the same as my `fillInput()` utility function:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('fillInput', {prevSubject: 'element'}, (subject, value) => {
  subject.clear();
  subject.type(value);
});
```

However, when I try this in a spec via:

```
cy.get('#my-selector').fillInput('my-value');
```

I get this error in the cypress browser console:

```
TypeError: subject.clear is not a function
```

In the docs, `cy.get()` is said to yield a DOM Element, and the `{prevSubject: 'element'}` should make `subject` to be the same type (as far as I understand this).

However, `subject` seems to be a different type and methods that work on elements like `type()` or ' clear()`or ' should()` does not work on child command subjects.

How can I get the `subject` of my child command to act as a Dom Element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While investigating to post the question, I came up with a simple solution to this problem. The `subject` is an object which has a `selector`, so you can use that selector with `cy.get(subject.selector)` to get the Dom Element:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('fillInput', {prevSubject: 'element'}, (subject, value) => {
  cy.get(subject.selector).clear().type(value);
});
```

I think this is not a lot of clear and more people may have this issue, so I leave my solution here.

Comment: This seems to be the wrong pattern, see [Best practices - Assigning Return Values](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Assigning-Return-Values), you should probably use `cy.get(subject.selector).clear().type(value)`

Comment: `subject` is a jQuery selector object containing selector and HTML elements selected

Comment: when i try cy.get(subject.selector) I get: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: ``, but never found it.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use

```
cy.wrap(subject)
```

For me that was the trick.

Comment: This is **the recommended way** in the cypress docs:
_Whenever you're using a child command you likely want to use `cy.wrap()` on the subject. Wrapping it enables you to immediately use more Cypress commands on that subject._ (Feb 2022)
Ref: Blue hint at end of section [Child Commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Child-Commands)